# Python KivyMD access widgets inside tabs

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Long story short, here's my code for a project of mine, simplified:

test.py

```
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase


class Tabs(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass

class Test(MDApp):
    pass

Test().run()
```

test.kv

```
MDFloatLayout:
    MDTabs:
        id: tabs

        Tabs:
            id: one
            title: 'one'

            MDLabel: #example widget that i want to access to like PLEASE
                id: label
                text: ';-;'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'center'

        Tabs:
            id: two
            title: 'two'

            MDRectangleFlatButton: #also this dabhfdvsfdgbjdkfmg
                id: button
                text: 'end my misery'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

Basically the problem here is that I can't figure out how to access to the `label` and the `button` widgets inside the individual tabs. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access any id in the root widget from the app class like this `self.root.ids.label`
you can do it in the build method

```py
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase


class Tabs(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # here you will get the text of the label using id
        print(self.root.ids.label.text)


Test().run()
```